# windows Service Controller application programming interface for driver service

Tags: drivers

Am supposed to develop a windows Service Controller application programming interface (API)  driver service drivers.   in visual studio 2017

Could someone put me through on the library or  C++ template i need  to install in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Visual Studio 2017, click on the Open Visual Studio installer to install a missing component 
"ASP.NET web development". When the installation finishes, create a new project and write your windows service with "Windows Classic desktop".

Check out this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx

Your  driver service  requires an in dept research  and  programming experience.

In my experience in writing windows service, I write it in C# and I write the driver service in C++.